# Erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Estou com o seguinte problema, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Quando estou em um site que executa o Javascript e dou um comando.

O erro acontece no mySaved.js.196

Segue a linha que eu clico neste site o JavaScript alega o problema e não executa o que teria que fazer:

```
function modifySaved(){
    var o_Element = document.getElementById(sourceElement.id);
    var applicationId = document.getElementById('applicationId').value;
    //pull report info string from the "reportInfoString" attribute
    var reportIdArrayStr = o_Element.reportInfoString;
    var reportIdArray = reportIdArrayStr.split('|'); //***NESTA LINHA O JAVASCRIPT DIZ QUE DÁ O PROBLEMA***
    var reportId = reportIdArray[0];
    var isShared = reportIdArray[1];
    var isScheduled = reportIdArray[2]; 
    var countryCode = reportIdArray[3];
    var divId = reportIdArray[4];

    modifySavedReport(reportId, isShared, isScheduled, countryCode, divId, applicationId);
}
```

Eu não entendo muito, se dá para identificar algo errado aí.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você obtém um elemento HTML da página:

```
var o_Element = document.getElementById(sourceElement.id);
```

Depois você procura o "reportInfoString" no elemento encontrado. Como o tipo Element não contém nada como esse nome, `undefined` é retornado.

```
var reportIdArrayStr = o_Element.reportInfoString;
```

Você tenta usar o método `split` no `undefined` e o seu JavaScript dá pau:

```
var reportIdArray = reportIdArrayStr.split('|');
```

Se houver um atributo chamado "reportInfoString" no elemento HTML encontrado, então o que você queria era isso:

```
var reportIdArrayStr = o_Element.getAttribute('reportInfoString');
```

Senão, talvez o que você queira seja outra coisa, mas o fato é que o seu `o_Element.reportInfoString` não faz o que você espera que deveria fazer.